# PHP7.3 startup warning messages

Tags: apache2, php

I am working with Ubuntu 18.04, Apache2 and have upgraded to PHP7.3 from PHP7.2 but I am getting warnings in my php log file indicating that something is not quite right.

PHP 7.3 is up and running and my `phpinfo()` confirms a range of modules are installed and running.

I am getting warnings of this form:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/bz2 (/usr/lib/php/20170718/bz2: cannot open shared object file...............
```

The modules giving the messages are:

```
bz2
curl
gd2
mysqli
pdo_mysql
ext-gd
xmlrpc
```

Of these all appear in `phpinfo`, and though gd2 or ext-gd don't explicitly appear, `gd` does.

To me the odd thing is that those warnings refer to trying to load from the `20170718` directory, yet PHP7.3 loads from the `20180731` directory.  During the upgrade to 7.3 I know I had to make sure I had the correct `phpize` and the new directory became `20180731`.  Looks to me as though there is some legacy stuff I need to clear.

In addition - modules `bcmath`, `fileinfo` and `mbstring` give met this type of warning:

```
Module 'bcmath' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

From what I have read, this can be due to trying to enable the extension twice - in `php.ini` and again in `bcmath.so` etc in the `config.d` directory - but this is not the case - they are commented out in `php.ini`.

This is not stopping me working but is filling up the log file with repeated warnings.

Can anyone tell me where the warnings are being generated and how to overcome them?